# Query any field in Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene, neo4j, elasticsearch

I tend to query for a specific field, eg.

```
title:*The Right Way* AND text:*The Right Way*
```

Is there a way to query *The Right Way* in any field I cannot no in advance?

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse a query using [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) or you can create a field which concatenates the content you would like to search and search only that field.